# Unable to locate package libgdal-java

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a Dockerfile based on Ubuntu 22.04 in which I need to add `libgdal-java`.

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && apt -y autoremove
RUN apt install -y gdal-bin
RUN apt install -y libgdal-java
```

When I run docker build I see the error below:

```
 => ERROR [5/5] RUN apt install -y libgdal-java                                                                                                                                                                              1.4s
------
 > [5/5] RUN apt install -y libgdal-java:
0.479 
0.479 WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
0.479 
0.507 Reading package lists...
1.209 Building dependency tree...
1.359 Reading state information...
1.365 E: Unable to locate package libgdal-java
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   5 |     RUN apt install -y default-jdk
   6 |     RUN apt install -y libgdal-dev
   7 | >>> RUN apt install -y libgdal-java
   8 |     
   9 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt install -y libgdal-java" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

How I can solve it?

**EDIT**

No trouble with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It's not part of Jammy, hence you can't find it. The question is, what do you need from it, so that you can figure out what would be the appropriate replacement.

Comment: @RickRackow I've to expand the list of file format that Geoserver can read as mentioned [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#linux-packages-and-setup)

Comment: You can search https://packages.ubuntu.com/ to try to find a package.  If it's a native Java library that you want to use in a Java application, listing it in your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` will probably be easier and more portable.

Comment: Easy solution could be to use a different base image, the package is available in Ubuntu 20.04. @DavidMaze unfortunately the maven package does not contain the native lib, so you would have to build this on your own and add it to the image.

Comment: @cyberbrain I know that with 20.04 there are no trouble. I would be use 22.04, but if there isn't a solution I'll use 20.04. I don't understand why `libgdal-java` is not in the list of package for 22.04

Comment: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-7412?focusedCommentId=84733 I think they're not really ready yet to upgrade to ubuntu 22.04 but evaluating

Comment: You can probably solve this with a multistage docker build too, where you build the package yourself in the first stage

Comment: Probably this solve the trouble but for me now isn't a real need use Ubuntu 22.04, so I will use 20.04 in meanwhile.